# SSL Self Signed Certificate Error

Tags: ssl

I have installed SSL Certificate manually that I had brought from Godadday. It installed successfully but it shows self signed certificate which is not trusted or displays cross on https.

What is the solution ?

Comment: Self signed certificates are not trusted because you SELF signed them... Use a TRUSTED Certificate authority and buy a certificate.

Comment: I had brought it from Godadday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing because it does not recognized the certificate that you get from Godaddy.
The CSR certificate has to upload on your site and make changes on apache config file.

Make sure your CSR file should not match with the private key that you submitted to verify your site.

Comment: How can i check my CSR is matched with the private key.

Comment: There are some online tool where you can checked https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

Comment: yes, my CSR is not matched with the private key, Now what i have to do?

Comment: then you again need to create private key with your site details and submitted to godaddy. they will return you with new CSR.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a SSL certificate requires some server administration knowhow, especially updating web server configuration.

DigitalOcean has a great tutorial on how to install a SSL certificate from GoDaddy: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority#example-ca-2-godaddy

Maybe it helps.

To check if you installed it correctly, you can use Qualys SSL Server Test at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html